# How can I add orge 3d as a view controller to my project

Tags: ios, ogre

I'm working in an 3D application and I need to load a big 3D model. cocos3D cannot render it but Ogre3d ([www.ogre3d.org](http://www.ogre3d.org)) can.

I try to add orge3d as a view controller but not luckily, I cannot. Orge3d create a uiwindow object that can get by

```
UIWindow* uiWindow;
RenderWindow* mWindow = Ogre::Root::getSingleton().getAutoCreatedWindow();
mWindow->getCustomAttribute("WINDOW", &uiWindow);
```

And my application is a navigation application, I need to push some view controller before adding 3D model so I don't know how to do this. Can anyone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ogre3d offers [`OgreView`](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/interfaceOgreView.html) and [`EAGLViewController`](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/interfaceEAGLViewController.html).

So, I believe you might instantiate the view or the controller directly and then init ogre through:

```
[self initOgreWithWnd:nil andView:glview];
```

or

```
[self initOgreWithWnd:nil andView:glController.view];
```

I would give a shot to instantiating the controller directly, although, it seems that making everything work correctly could be more complex than this, as shown by [this discussion](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=71508).